# Python3 - TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.x, traceback

I'm recently taking a Python course and the exercise I'm working on wants me to find the largest and smallest number. If I put in a "string" then it would prompt "Invalid Input." Here is what I got so far but I'm getting a traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "FindingSmallestLargestNum.py", line 15, in <module>
    if num > largest:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 
'NoneType'
```

Here are my lines of code:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True: 
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done": break
    try:
        num = float(num)
except:
    print("Invalid input")
    continue

    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num

print("Maximum is",int(largest))
print("Minimum is",int(smallest))
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error code. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: The error indicates that `num` (a float) is being compared to `largest` (a `NoneType`). It means `largest` hasn't been initialized to a type suitable for the `float` comparison. Try changing the init value of `largest` from `None` to `0`.

Comment: Just a quick heads up, @tony19, that won't actually work if the first number entered is negative - it will consider 0 the current largest value. Better would be to do for `largest` what you're currently doing for `smallest`, though you can simplify it as per my answer - only `smallest` needs to be `None` at the start.

Comment: @paxdiablo Ah, good catch

Answer (score 10):

With regard to:

```
if smallest is None:
    smallest = num
```

You correctly set `smallest` to the first value but you do *not* do the same for `largest`.

That means, for the first value, the expression `num > largest` will be equivalent to `FloatVariable > NoneVariable`, which is the cause of the error you're seeing.

A better approach would be something like:

```
if smallest is None:
    smallest = num
    largest = num
elif num > largest:
    largest = num
elif num < smallest:
    smallest = num
```

This has the advantage of using the knowledge that `smallest` and `largest`  will either *both* be `None` at the start, or *both* non-`None` after the first value (the first value will inherently be both the current minimum *and* maximum).

It also does not do the second `if` block for the first value - that's not necessary now that you're setting `smallest` *and* `largest` for that value.

---

Having re-found this question three years or so after I answered it, and after a fair bit more Python experience under the belt, it appears to me we could make it more succinct (which often leads to better maintainability:

```py
smallest, largest = None, None

while True: 
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        num = float(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    if smallest is None:
        smallest, largest = num, num
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num

print(f"Maximum is {largest}")
print(f"Minimum is {smallest}")
```

Comment: Thank you both for your input into this. I understand whats going on and using your approach I was able to complete my small program!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work for sure but I think assignment already had it None value in it so that meant they want us to use None value it took me a little bit time but I did how they want it
Good luck

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        numbers = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if largest is None:
        largest = numbers 
    elif numbers > largest:
        largest = numbers
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = numbers
    elif numbers < smallest:
        smallest = numbers
print("Maximum is", largest)   
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```